# How should a parent style a child component for Angular? I'd like a good solution that won't be deprecated

Tags: css, angular, components, parent-child, transclusion

When I need a component to change slightly for a new use, I've looked at transclusion and  multi-slot transclusion vs adding HTML around the component but there are still situations where a component's internal styling needs to be changed.

Answer (score 0):

Components should be self contained and programmed so they don't require refactoring whenever a new use is needed.

One solution is to add a class to the parent using ng-class, and then use regular css rules to style the child: one set of rules that requires the class to be on the parent div, and another set that doesn’t require the class to be on the parent div.

Example css:

```
.my_class {Normal styling}
.my_parent_div_class .my_class {Special styling goes here}
```

Comment: Can you expand you answer with examples? It's hard to follow the solution you describe

Answer (score 0):

You can pass a style in as an input, and then set it in the template with [ngStyle].

So for a simple example i'll show how to do this with a background color.

customComponent.html

```
<div [ngStyle]="{'background-color': data?.backgroundColor }">
   <p> the background color will be set from an input </p>
</div>
```

customComponent.ts

```
  @Input('data') 
  data: {
    backgroundColor: string;
  };
```

parent.html

```
<customComponent [data]="{backgroundColor: 'grey'}"></customComponent>
```